# Get the name of a field from a class without an instance

Tags: c#, reflection, lambda, func

So I use the following utility to get the name of a field/property from an instance of a class...

```
public static string FieldName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> Source)
{
    return ((MemberExpression)Source.Body).Member.Name;
}
```

This allows me to do the following:

```
public class CoolCat
{
    public string KaratePower;
}

public class Program
{
    public static Main()
    {
        public CoolCat Jimmy = new CoolCat();

        string JimmysKaratePowerField = FieldName(() => Jimmy.KaratePower);
    }
}
```

This is great for serialization and other times when I need a string representation of the field name.

But now, I want to be able to get the field name WITHOUT having an instance of the class - for instance, if I am setting up a table and want to dynamically link the FieldNames of the columns to actual fields in a class (so refactorings, etc. will not break it).

Basically, I feel like I just don't quite get the syntax of how to accomplish this, but I imagine that it will look something like this:

```
public static string ClassFieldName<T>(Func<T> PropertyFunction)
{
     // Do something to get the field name?  I'm not sure whether 'Func' is the right thing here - but I would imagine that it is something where I could pass in a lambda type expression or something of the sort?
}

public class Program
{
    public static Main()
    {
        string CatsPowerFieldName = ClassFieldName<CoolCat>((x) => x.KaratePower);

        // This 'CatsPowerFieldName' would be set to "KaratePower".
    }
}
```

I hope that makes sense - I'm not very good with the vocab around this subject so I know that the question is a little vague.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have two methods I use to do this.

The first is an extension method that can be used on any object.

```
public static string GetPropertyName<TEntity, TProperty>(this TEntity entity, Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> propertyExpression)
{
    return propertyExpression.PropertyName();
}
```

Which is used like

```
public CoolCat Jimmy = new CoolCat();
string JimmysKaratePowerField = Jimmy.GetPropertyName(j => j.KaratePower);
```

The second I use when I don't have an object.

```
public static string PropertyName<T>(this Expression<Func<T, object>> propertyExpression)
{
        MemberExpression mbody = propertyExpression.Body as MemberExpression;

        if (mbody == null)
        {
            //This will handle Nullable<T> properties.
            UnaryExpression ubody = propertyExpression.Body as UnaryExpression;

            if (ubody != null)
            {
                mbody = ubody.Operand as MemberExpression;
            }

            if (mbody == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Expression is not a MemberExpression", "propertyExpression");
            }
        }

        return mbody.Member.Name;
}
```

This can be used like so

```
string KaratePowerField = Extensions.PropertyName<CoolCat>(j => j.KaratePower);
```

Comment: I really like this solution - could you maybe elaborate about the section that you added handling Nullable<T> properties?  When would this section of code be used?

Comment: If KaratePower is a `Nullable<T>` or `T?` such as `int?` or `DateTime?`, then the body will not be a MemberExpression, it will be a UnaryExpression.  From there, you need to take the UnaryExpression's Operand to get the correct MemberExpression.

Answer (score 4):

What you're trying to do is one of the reasons Microsoft created System.Reflection
Try [this](http://www.csharp-examples.net/reflection-property-names/):

```
using System.Reflection;  // reflection namespace

public static List<Type> GetClassPropertyNames(Type myClass)
        {
            PropertyInfo[] propertyInfos;
            propertyInfos = myClass.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public);

            List<Type> propertyTypeNames = new List<Type>();

            // write property names
            foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in propertyInfos)
            {
                propertyTypeNames .Add(propertyInfo.PropertyType);
            }

            return propertyNames;

        }
```

Comment: Note that this will return all public static properties. In the example a nonstatic field is used.

Comment: I'm not sure that this helps me - I want to have a method that i can call that returns the string name of the field of a given class - how can I turn the above into something like that?

Comment: @William I've updated my example with your request, you can call it using: GetClassPropertyNames(typeof(CoolCat));

Comment: But i don't want a list of string names - I want to be able to refer to the name of a SPECIFIC field when binding some UI component to a field - i.e. like when setting the field name property of a data column.

Comment: @William Well using reflection you can convert from a type name to a Type object, but thankfully the PropertyInfo object has a field PropertyType which returns the Type object. I've edited my answer again to return List<Type>

Answer (score 2):

I believe using Reflection will be useful here. I do not have VS with me right now, but I'm sure you can do something like typeof(class).GetMembers(). My reflection is a little rusty.